# CSS Percentage height & auto width not creating aspect ratio in IE

Tags: css, height, width, percentage

I looked all over and couldnt find a solution. I want to set the percentage height of an image and keep the aspect ratio for the width.

Doesnt work for height in IE:

```
img{
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Does work for width in IE:

```
img{
    height: auto;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: it depends if you have set a height for the parent. If the parent has no height, the img doesnt know what height it should have.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage declarations are a percent of the parent element not the element you are declaring it on. The reason width works is because your containing block elements i.e. `display:block` will span the page by default. If you assign a fixed height to the parent then it will work as you expect.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
img{
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```